# Obtener object de un listado

Tags: javascript

Supongamos que tengo lo siguiente:

```
var ids = [1,5]
var persons = [{id:1, name:'stack'},{id:2, name:'stack2'},
              {id:3, name:'stack3'},{id:4, name:'stack4'},{id:5, name:'stack5'}]
```

Entonces necesito del listados de "persons" todos los que tengan id: 1 y 5.
Podriá hacer un "for" de persons y comprobar si el id existe dentro del array "ids", pero claro si tuviese 100000 persons no creo que sea muy eficiente, hay alguna otra mejor manera?

```
var result = []
for (var co in persons) {
    if (id.indexOf(persons[co].id) > 0) {
        result.add(persons[co])
    }           
}
```

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta, por ejemplo, qué resultado hay que generar de esa comprobación. ¿Hay que extraer algo de cada objeto, no hay que extraer nada, hay que crear un dato nuevo (que puede ser por ejemplo algo como `stack:true, stack2:false...`) según se encuentre o no la persona. Creo que todos esos detalles son imprescindibles de cara a una respuesta. Pon ejemplos claros de ello y dinos también si has investigado algo. Gracias.

Comment: Si tienes 100000 `persons` igual tienes que plantearte fragmentar los datos o hacer el filtrado en BBDD (si es que los obtienes de ahí). En todo caso el `for` es más eficiente que otras alternativas como `filter`,`map`, `reduce`, etc.

Comment: Si tienes el array ordenado puedes hacer una búsqueda binaria

Comment: he modificado mi pregunta con la solución que tenga provisionalmente, @kiko_l ya vienen esos 10000 registros de la bbdd y esta filtrado

Comment: , @pablo lozano, no viene ordenado el arrary pero siemrpe se peude ordenar si mejora el rendimiento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar el método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para generar el listado con los objetos deseados.

Según la documentación, el método `filter()` del tipo `Array`, crea un nuevo `Array` con los elementos que pasan la condición de filtro.

En cuanto a la eficiencia no sabría decirte si es o no más eficiente que un bucle `for`, probablemente sea exactamente igual, pero lo que si es seguro es que se ve más elegante.

Un ejemplo de cómo quedaría:

```js
var ids = [1,5];
var persons = [{id:1, name:'stack'},{id:2, name:'stack2'},
              {id:3, name:'stack3'},{id:4, name:'stack4'},{id:5, name:'stack5'}];
var filteredPersons = persons.filter((person) => {
  var pass = false;
  ids.forEach((id) => {
    if(person.id == id) {
      pass = true;
    }
  });
  return pass;
});

console.log(filteredPersons);
```

**EDICIÓN**

Como @Kiko_L comenta, si usas `indexOf()` te ahorras el `map` y el código se ve más conciso. Por ejemplo:

```js
var ids = [1,5];
var persons = [{id:1, name:'stack'},{id:2, name:'stack2'},
              {id:3, name:'stack3'},{id:4, name:'stack4'},{id:5, name:'stack5'}];
var filteredPersons = persons.filter((person) => {
  return ids.indexOf(person.id) >= 0 ? true : false;
});

console.log(filteredPersons);
```

Comment: realmente haces un for de persons, no seria mejor que sea un for de ids, creo que daria menos vueltas?

Comment: El bucle `for` es bastante más eficiente (principalmente porque no tiene callbacks)

Comment: Pues daría las mismas, cada *id* debes compararlo con cada *person*. Si tengo 100 mil *person* y dos *id* haré 200 mil comparaciones: 2 por cada *person*, si lo hago al revés, es decir tengo 2 *id* y 100 mil *person* haré igual 200 mil comparaciones: 100 mil por cada *id*. 

Comment: Como comenta @Kiko_L, un bucle `for` en su estado puro (sin callbacks) debe ser más eficiente. Creo que no tienes muchas alternativas. Por eso en mi respuesta te dije que no estaba seguro que usar `filter` fuese más eficiente. En todo caso, es un método elegante que realiza la tarea. Si lo que deseas es eficiencia tal vez no te sirva. Igual puedes probar tiempos de ejecución ponderados y decides. Saludos

Comment: Con `indexOf` podrías ahorrarte el `map`.

Answer (score 5):

Asumiendo que haces la búsqueda una vez y luego mantienes esa lista de elementos durante mucho tiempo y vas a tener que buscar muchas veces, puede valer la pena procesar los datos previamente y guardarlos en un objeto o en un Map (no hay mucha diferencia en velocidad de acceso) :

```
const persons = [{id:1, name:'stack'},{id:2, name:'stack2'},
              {id:3, name:'stack3'},{id:4, name:'stack4'},{id:5, name:'stack5'}]

const personsMap= {}; // new Map();
persons.forEach(element => personsMap[element.id]=element);
// persons.forEach(element => personsMap.set(element.id,element));

function getPersonById(id) {
  return personsMap[id];
  //return personsMap.get(id);
}
```

Otra opción sería obtener esos datos ya ordenados, con lo que podrías hacer una [búsqueda binaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_binaria):

1. Tienes N elementos en un Array, ordenados.
2. Quieres obtener el elemento con valor X.
3. Buscas el elemento en la mitad: M= N/2
4. Comparas con la posición M.
5. Si has encontrado el elemento, hemos terminado.
6. Si el elemento en la posición M es menor, entonces el que buscas estará en la mitad más grande, desde M hasta M *2, así que hacemos M = M + M/2 y vamos al paso 3.
7. Si el elemento en la posición M era mayor, entonces M= M - M/2 y vamos al paso 3

Comment: Pablo, ¿dónde comparas los `id` de cada persona con este array en tu código: `[1,5]`?

Comment: Mi código se deshace del array una vez se ha pasado todo al mapa, simplemente se accedería haciendo dos llamadas a `getPersonById`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Traduciendo de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143863/10053314), tienes diferentes maneras:

Para IE9 o superior:

```
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
 if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
  {

       Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement /*, fromIndex */)

    {


    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (len === 0)
      return -1;

    var n = 0;
    if (arguments.length > 0)
    {
      n = Number(arguments[1]);
      if (n !== n)
        n = 0;
      else if (n !== 0 && n !== (1 / 0) && n !== -(1 / 0))
        n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
    }

    if (n >= len)
      return -1;

    var k = n >= 0
          ? n
          : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    for (; k < len; k++)
    {
      if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
        return k;
    }
    return -1;
  };

}
```

[Daniel James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143847/best-way-to-find-if-an-item-is-in-a-javascript-array#144172):

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex == null) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
    }
    for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

roosteronacid(enlace roto):

```
Array.prototype.hasObject = (
  !Array.indexOf ? function (o)
  {
    var l = this.length + 1;
    while (l -= 1)
    {
        if (this[l - 1] === o)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  } : function (o)
  {
    return (this.indexOf(o) !== -1);
  }
);
```

Te invito a pasar por la web en ingles y que leas también [how do i check if an array includes an object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript/25765186#25765186)

Comment: nicolas veo mucho codigo pero no me queda claro cual debo usar segun mi ejemplo, como lo modificarias? de esa forma podria ver cuanto tiempo tarda tu forma respecto a la mia

Comment: @sirdaiz básicamente haciendo `tuArray.includes('loQueBuscas');` te devolverá un bool

Comment: Si no me equivoco, lo que quiere el OP es devolver los objetos, no si está o no está en el `array`